# how to add items ( elements ) to a MutableList from WEB using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, kotlin, mutablelist

I need to add elements to my MutableList from web using Kotlin.
I have a folder containing a lot of books that I want to get the title and the link of every book and add it the to the Mutable List

I have a link of a book in google drive like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By8giYopjXKPQTJqZUN5Z2l1ZGc/view?usp=sharing) and i want to add The title and the link of the book to my LIST :

```
var booksList:MutableList<Book> = ArrayList()
bookslist.add(Book("I WANT TO ADD THE TITLE HERE","AND THE LINK HERE"))
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your code already does what you are asking for.

Comment: i have a folder contain a lo of books i want to get the title and the link of every book and add it the to the Mutable List